# sorting bins two at a time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm stumped by the following problem in the case where there are only 4 bins.  I can do it for 6 or 8 but not 4.  Also, can someone help me come up with a generalized algorithm for this?

You have n bins (arranged in alternate order of B A B A ...) that you can move 2 at a time and are given 2n slots. Sort them so that in the end all the "A" bins are left of all the "B" bins.  They should all be adjacent, i.e. no gaps at the end.  For example:

_ _ _ _ B A B A

Thanks

Edit: yes you have to move two adjacent bins at a time into two adjacent spots.

Edit 2: No you can't transpose the bins.  Here's an example with 6 bins:

_ _ _ _ _ _ B A B A B A

_ _ _ _ A B B _ _ A B A

_ _ _ _ A B B B A A _ _

_ _ A A A B B B _ _ _ _

Comment: When you move 2 bins, do they have to move into adjacent spots? and When you pick two bins to move, do you have to pick two adjacent bins? As stated it's not very clear..

Comment: When you move 2 bins, can you transpose them as you move them?  (I.e. `__BA` => `AB__`?  When you move 2 bins into two adjacent spots, do those spots need to be empty?

Comment: Bin to slot movement rules seem a bit ambiguous.  Is this transition sequence allowed? `____BABA => __BABA__ => __B__AAB => AAB____B => AABB____`

Comment: sorry I didn't explain it right: only two adjacent bins can be moved at a time onto two empty adjacent slots without transposing them.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Are you sure it's solvable in the general case? (Or even in particular for 4 bins)?

Comment: It's obvious that the case of 2 bins cannot be solved.. So maybe it's worth trying to prove that 4 bins is not solvable either

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward breadth-first search of reachable positions for the 4 bins case showed that it cannot actually be solved.  Here is rough pseudo-code so you can try writing that for yourself:

```
todo_queue = ["____BABA", []]
path_to_position = {}
while things in todo_queue:
    (position, path) = todo_queue.next()
    if position in path_to_position:
        continue # We've been here before.
    if position is success:
        print path
        EXIT HERE
    for my move in possible_moves(position):
        todo_queue.add([position after move, path + [move]])
```

For a general solution, it suffices to do that breadth-first search for the cases of 6, 8, 10 and 12 bins as special cases.  For any larger even numbers bins you can solve one of those 4 to create the middle of the solution, and then solve blocks of 8.  You can then easily move around and rearrange those solved blocks pair by pair to a final solution.